# zoom the screen in qooxdoo desktop with pinch

Tags: mobile, zooming, desktop, qooxdoo

I am currently developing a qooxdoo desktop application and want to be able to use it with mobile browsers too. The application opens without problems and is
displayed correctly, but I cannot use the pinch gesture to zoom the
screen. Please help me!

In my index.html, already has this tag :

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.1, minimum-scale=0, maximum-scale=10.0, user-scalable=1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There is `qx.event.type.Pinch` which gets fired on widgets you 'pinch' just listen to the `pinch` event and do something appropriate ...

Relying on the finer points "viewport" meta may not be very portable ...